# Office Add-In - viewport size issue

Tags: internet-explorer, office-js, office-addins

I am working on an Office Word add-in using Angular 5. I have a weird issue where clicking on any route link scales the viewport zoom level down by a small percentage each click until everything is very small. I have set the location strategy to hash.

- I have removed all css and still experience the issue.
- Tried with and without viewport meta tag and @-ms-viewport css property with various settings.
- Tried setting the X-UA-Compatible meta tag to various versions of IE.

Wondering if anyone has experienced similar.

**Update:**

I have tried with the following add-in and experience the same issue by clicking on the route links.
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Word-Add-in-Angular2-StyleChecker

[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Office Add In</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <base href="/">
  <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Main Template

```
<div class="root-navigation">
    <div class="navigation-links">
        <a routerLink="/tab1" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
            Tab 1
        </a>
        <a routerLink="/tab2" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
            Tab 2
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="root-viewport">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: This answer won't contain a solution to the problem, because it would be too long to post as a comment.

---

TL;DR: It looks like there's a bug in Word 2016 for Windows that affects `window.devicePixelRatio` for OfficeJS add-ins that use Angular's Router. This bug does not occur on Word Online using either IE11 or Chrome.

**Version Numbers:**

Windows 10:
Version 1709 (OS Build 16299.125)

Word 2016:
Version 1801 (Build 8911.2016 Click-to-Run) (Office Insider)
WordApi 1.3

Internet Explorer 11:
Version 11.125.16299.0
Update Versions: 11.0.49 (KB4052978)

---

Longer Version: I also noticed this and thought it was Angular's router. By logging the value of `window.devicePixelRatio`, I could see that its value was steadily decreasing with each router navigation. Bizarre, given that [it's supposed to be read-only](https://www.caniuse.com/#search=devicePixelRatio)!

So I spent some time [creating a simple repro](https://github.com/TheSamsterZA/office-js-device-pixel-ratio-ie11-bug/tree/no-office-js) as preparation for [opening a ticket on their GitHub repo](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues).

However, I could not reproduce the problem with my extremely simple example on Chrome and IE11.

So, I added OfficeJS to the example [in a separate branch](https://github.com/TheSamsterZA/office-js-device-pixel-ratio-ie11-bug/tree/master) and did some testing. Here are my findings:

### [Simple Angular App](https://github.com/TheSamsterZA/office-js-device-pixel-ratio-ie11-bug/tree/no-office-js)

In this scenario, there is no OfficeJS. I access the app using browsers directly.

- The initial value of `window.devicePixelRatio` on Chrome and IE11 is `1`.
- Navigating between tabs **does not** change this value.

### [OfficeJS Add-in](https://github.com/TheSamsterZA/office-js-device-pixel-ratio-ie11-bug/tree/master)

Here, the add-in is loaded by the host (Word Online or Word 2016 for Windows), which runs in its own browser process. [Side-loading manifest info here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins).

**Word Online**

- The initial value of `window.devicePixelRatio` on Chrome in Word Online is `1`.
- The initial value of `window.devicePixelRatio` on IE11 in Word Online is also `1`.
- Navigating between tabs *in either browser* **does not** change this value.

**Word 2016 for Windows**

- The initial value of `window.devicePixelRatio` on IE11 in Word 2016 is `1`.
- Navigating between tabs **does** change this value! Specifically, the value decreases, and with enough navigations, the content of the add-in appears to shrink.

So yeah, you're not crazy. :) Maybe someone from the OfficeJS team could help with this?

Comment: Looks like they are already aware of the issue.

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/40